# Why are more easily oxidized elements more reactive than less easily oxidized elements?

Tags: redox

Why do the more easily oxidized elements displace the less easily oxidized elements?

Question inspired by Activity Series of Metals

Comment: The title is asking "why are more reactive things more reactive?" In fact the whole question seems a little like that.

Answer (score 2):

Ease of oxidation is how easily it loses electrons. Electrons are the basis of chemical reactions. If chemical A is more easily oxidized than B, then B is a relative oxidizer to A, so in terms of the activity series, the elements that are more easily oxidized can react with more chemicals, since they will be able to act as reducing agents to more chemicals.